# Изменение значения переменной при считывании ее из файла

Tags: c++, алгоритм, структуры, регистрация

Имеется часть кода:

```
struct Accounts {
        string login;
        string password;
        int role;
    };
    int main() {
//От роли будет зависеть админ ты, или пользователь
        int role;
//Стартовое меню
        startingMenu(role);
//В зависимости от роли выбираем либо функционал админа, либо пользователя. 2 - роль пользователя, который зарегистрировался как админ, но еще не подтвержден
        switch (role) {
        case 1: adminMode();
            break;
        case 0: userMode();
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "Wait, when you would be accepted by admin!" << endl;
            break;
        }
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    void loginUser(int &role) {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter your login" << endl;
        string input_login;
        cin >> input_login;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter your password" << endl;
        string input_password;
        cin >> input_password;
        Accounts accounts;
//Флаг, который будет фиксировать, найден ли пользователь с таким логином и паролем или нет
        bool flag = false;
//Открываем файл, в котором содержатся логины, пароли и роли каждого пользователя
        ifstream list("list.txt");
        if (list.is_open()) {
//Ищем пользователя с введенным логином и паролем
            while (list >> accounts.login >> accounts.password >> role) {
                if (input_password == accounts.password && input_login == accounts.login) {
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            list.close();
        }
        else {
            writeThatFileCannotBeOpened();
        }
        cout << endl;
        if (flag) {
            cout << "Enter successed!" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Enter failed! Please, try again." << endl;
            loginUser(role);
        }
    }
    void adminMode() {
//По умолчанию, роль админа = 1
        int role = 1;
        while (true) {
//В меню админа представлен список действий, доступных админу. При нажатии цифры 3, выходим в стартовое меню выхода или регистрации
            switch (adminMenu()) {
            case 3:
                startingMenu(role);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    void userMode() {
//По умолчанию, роль пользователя= 0
        int role = 0;
        while (true) {
//В меню пользователя представлен список действий, доступных пользователю. При нажатии цифры 4, выходим в стартовое меню выхода или регистрации
            switch (userMenu())
            {
            case 4:
                startingMenu(role);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
void startingMenu(int &role) {
    cout << "1 - registration" << endl;
    cout << "2 - login" << endl;
//Переменная, в которой будет значение, которое выбрано: регистрация или вход
    int choise = 0;
//Флаг для проверки того, что пользователь выбрал либо регистрацию, либо вход
    bool flag = false;
    while (true) {
//Выбор, регистрация или вход
        cin >> choise;
        switch (choise)
        {
        case 1: 
            registrateUser(role);
            flag = true;
            break;
        case 2: loginUser(role);
            flag = true;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Choose 1 or 2!" << endl;
            break;
        }
        if (flag) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Задача - реализация функционала администратора и пользователя. Однако столкнулся со следующей проблемой: если зайти как администратор, выйти, а потом зайти как пользователь, то все равно зайдет в режим администратора, хотя у этого аккаунта role = 0, а значит должен зайти как пользователь. В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void startingMenu(int &role) {
    cout << "1 - registration" << endl;
    cout << "2 - login" << endl;
    int choise = 0;
    bool flag = false;
    while (true) {
        cin >> choise;
        switch (choise)
        {
        case 1: 
            registrateUser(role);
            flag = true;
            break;
        case 2: loginUser(role);
            flag = true;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Choose 1 or 2!" << endl;
            break;
        }
        if (flag) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Сдесь вы вводите через `cin` переменную, но при этом используете `role`, которую, между прочим, даже не проиницилизировали, для вызова `registrateUser`.